# Getting position of a coordinate on the surface of a sphere

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, coordinates, polar-coordinates

There is an object A. I want to create a object B. I'm trying to avoid that A covers B:

[image: A hides B from camera]

I have thinking how to achieve that. Take a look of the following drawing:

[image: A does not hide B from camera]

I have been thinking in a solution in a math - geometry way before searching for some Unity3D function to solve the problem. I have realise A and B would be on the same surface if the camera is within a sphere with radius c-A. So I guess the solution can be related to get a point at a B at a distance A-B from A on the surface of the sphere with radius c-A. Does it has sense? Any other idea? How to do it with maths and Unity?

Comment: By "close" to `A` do you mean on the same sphere? I'm a little confused by your description.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog it's hard to describe for me. I could be far also, so I'm going to remove the word "close" to the description to avoid more confusions. Both A and B are on the surface of the sphere. B is at a distance "A-B" from A.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a *ring* on the sphere's surface whose plane is perpendicular to the direction `c-A`.

This is fairly simple to compute. First we need to find 2 perpendicular vectors to `c-A` (we'll call this `d`):

- Call the vector `"c-A" = d`, the radius of the sphere `R = abs(d)` and the distance `"A-B" = D`.
- If `d.X / R < 0.5`, set a temporary vector `w = X`, else set `w = Y`.
- Compute the first perpendicular vector `u = normalize(cross(w, d))`.
- Compute the second one `v = normalize(cross(d, u))`.

The center point of this ring is given by `c + d * cos(D / R)`. From here we can generate any point on the ring with

```
p(t) = c + d * cos(D / R) + u * cos(t) + v * sin(t)   ,   0 ≤ t ≤ 2π
```

---

UPDATE:

[image]

Comment: @ReblochonMasque just a quick 10-minute model in SketchUp